# Ionic 2 Waiting for multiple responses

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having some problems with my app login page. I'm new with Ionic 2 and Angular and I have tried to figure this out with help of Google but no success so far...

These lines here are causing the problem, alert is returning "undefined" as soon as I click login button, even thought it should wait for response.

```
let accessToken = this.getAccessToken();
let details     = this.getProfileDetails(accessToken);
alert(JSON.stringify(details));
```

Whole code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FbProvider } from '../../providers/fb-provider';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  platform
  fb
  email
  name
  id

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, pf: Platform, fbProvider: FbProvider, public http: Http) {
    this.platform = pf;
    this.fb = fbProvider;
    this.email = '';
    this.name = '';
    this.id = '';
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello LoginPage Page');
  }

  fbLogin() {
    let accessToken = this.getAccessToken();
    let details     = this.getProfileDetails(accessToken);
    alert(JSON.stringify(details));
  }

  getAccessToken(){
    this.fb.login().then((fbLoginData) => {
      let params = new FormData();
      params.append('facebookAccessToken', fbLoginData.authResponse.accessToken);
      this.http.post('http://myHostUrl/api/accessToken', params).map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          return data.accessToken;
        },err => {
          alert(err);
        }
      );
    },(err) => {
      alert('Facebook login failed');
    });
  }

  getProfileDetails(accessToken){
    let params = new FormData();
    params.append('accessToken', accessToken);
    this.http.post('http://myHostUrl/api/userDetails', params).map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        return data;
      },err => {
        alert(err);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: `even thought it should wait for response` - explain why your code should wait for an asynchronous operation (`let details     = this.getProfileDetails(accessToken);`) to complete before continuing to the next line of code

Comment: in fact `let accessToken = this.getAccessToken();` is also an asynchronous function that doesn't return a value, therefore the accessToken in `let details     = this.getProfileDetails(accessToken);` will also be undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined because you need to wait the asynchronous functions to finish. The following code it's done with rxjs to manage the asynchrony of the two functions and the http calls. try it.

```
  fbLogin() {
    this.getAccessToken()
      .switchMap(accessToken => this.getProfileDetails(accessToken))
      .first() // Just one and complete ....
      .subscribe(
        details => alert(JSON.stringify(details)),
        error => alert(error)
      );
  }

  getAccessToken() : Observable<any> {

    return Observable.fromPromise(<Promise<any>> this.fb.login())
      .map(fbLoginData => fbLoginData.authResponse.accessToken)
      .switchMap(accessToken => {
        let params = new FormData();
        params.append('facebookAccessToken', accessToken);
        return this.http.post('http://myHostUrl/api/accessToken', params)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .map(data => data.accessToken)
      });

  }

  getProfileDetails(accessToken) : Observable<any>{

    let params = new FormData();
    params.append('accessToken', accessToken);
    return this.http.post('http://myHostUrl/api/userDetails', params).map(res => res.json());

  }
```